# Turning off second DHCP makes devices disappear

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have a modem with an included WIFI router and LAN ports.
To that modem, I attached an ASUS WIFI router and a NAS.
To the ASUS router, I attached a sound receiver.

I had some issues because of both the modem and the router running a DHCP server.
Therefore I turned off the DHCP at the ASUS router because the modem is serving IP addresses. But now the sound receiver does suddenly disappear from the network.

My question now is what is the best configuration?

Should I run the DHCP on the modem or on the router?
Or on both with a defined, not overlapping, IP range?

Also: I found out that when the ASUS is connected to the modem via the WAN port I experience massive amounts of package loss. That is not the case when I connect both via the LAN port.

Comment: It is easiest by far to have one subnet in your small network and have one (only) DHCP server. If you use your ISP modem/router subnet and network, put the DHCP server there. If your own router sets up the subnet and network, use DHCP in your router. But have only  one DHCP server

Comment: Thanks @John! My own router creates the WIFI we are using. But the modem connects to the NAS which we connect to. So I should set up the DHCP on the router?
Also: Since I plugged the router to the modem via LAN (instead of WAN) I can not access the admin panel of the router anymore. Anything wrong with this config?

Comment: Connect a LAN port on your WiFi router to a LAN port on the modem. Give the WiFi Router a static IP on the modem and then turn DHCP OFF on the WiFi router. That also puts everything on one subnet.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a modem with an included WIFI router and LAN ports. To that
> modem, I attached an ASUS WIFI router and a NAS. To the ASUS router, I
> attached a sound receiver.

Try to get to one network, one subnet, and one DHCP server. This is so much simpler to manage in the end.

You can do this with your above setup.

Consider your Modem/Router to be your main network with the DCHP server here.

Perhaps at this point, reset your second ASUS WiFi router to factory specifications.

Now hook up a LAN port on the ASUS Router to a LAN port on your main network.

Give the ASUS Router a static IP address on the main network (that is, an IP address that is not within the DHCP range of the main router).

Turn DHCP OFF on the ASUS router and do a soft reset of the ASUS router (turn off, turn on).

Now everything is on one network (and that means all your devices are on one network). DHCP comes from the main router.

You can set up Wireless on either or both of the routers. If you set up wireless on both, use the same SSID and wireless credentials so that you can move between them.

This is a fairly normal setup and should work well for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the easy-to-understand explanation!
I will try that and already tried parts of it. Right now the ASUS router only has internet connectivity if I connect it on the WAN port. When I plug the cable coming from the modem into the ASUS' LAN I don't have internet access. Not sure why though?

Comment: Be sure to follow all the steps and connect LAN port to LAN port. Do not use the ASUS WAN port in this setup.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will follow the instructions next week and will update you.

Comment: I tried it exactly like described, there is one issue: if I set the ASUS to "router-mode", it only works if connected to the WAN port (with package loss). If I connect it to the LAN, I won't have an internet connection (it looks for a modem, not a modem+router to be connected to). If I set the router to "AP-Mode" (connected via LAN port) it works but most of the ASUS functionality (Firewall, etc) is disabled. What am I supposed to do? Thanks!

Comment: I think at this point you should try a different router. This should be  straightorward with any ordinary router. You might ask ASUS support to see if you have the correct device for the situation.